# Installing pre-requisites for forest classification using SCP and QGIS?

Tags: qgis-plugins, installation, digital-image-processing

I am using QGIS 2.8.6 and I want to use SCP for forest classification from Landsat 8 oli. I  have already installed the SPP plugin.

What else do I need to install for operation of the software?

Answer (score 1):

You could check their website:

[Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin for QGIS](http://fromgistors.blogspot.com/p/semi-automatic-classification-plugin.html)

Or more specifically, the [Plugin Installation page](http://fromgistors.blogspot.com/p/plugin-installation2.html) which provides a step-by-step guide on how to install the plugin and the several packages required:

- [GDAL/OGR](http://www.gdal.org/)
- [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/)
- [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/)
- [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib python-scipy python-numpy
```

**PS: GDAL/OGR already installed.**